# JQuery Mobile Collapsible Text Orientation (Position)

Tags: jquery-mobile

I am developing something in a Right-To-Left (RTL) language and I need the text in the collapsible to be positioned on the right as opposed to the default left.

Here is the code:

```
<div id="content_c1" data-role="collapsible" data-iconpos="right" align="right">
    <h3>Right to Left Text</h3>
    <p>Right to Left Content</p>
</div>
<div id="content_c2" data-role="collapsible">
    <h3></h3>
    <p></p>
</div>
```

The first collapsible is Right to Left. The `data-iconpos="right"` nicely movees the icon to the right and the `align="right"` moves the content in the `<p>` to the right. But the text shown in `<h3>` stays on the left.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This is working for me:

```
.ui-collapsible h3 .ui-btn-inner
{
    text-align:right;
}
```

Comment: i am haveing the same problem :  <div data-role="collapsible" data-iconpos="right" data-mini="true" >
            <h3>test1 </h3>
    <p align="center">test2</p>
            <a href="#" data-transition="slide" data-theme="b" data-role="button" style="background-color:red" >edit</a> 
            </div>  i tryd to add this to my css but it didnt help any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there is a better way but you could try this.

```
.ui-btn-text{float:right}​
```

Answer (score 0):

Having the same problem...

This one solved it :

```
.ui-collapsible-heading .ui-btn  {
            text-align: right;
}
```